# Checking against JSONObject returning null

Tags: java, json

I've been banging my head on a seemingly easy thing for hours. I have a simple service that goes out and returns some json from an API. In most scenarios a successfull return yields something like:

```
{"userId":"GyOjEqOM97B","userName":"marcos","userPermissions":"admin"}
```

But in some cases I'm simple getting a response of null. Not an empty JSON array but just null. I tried to do a null check against the response.toString() since that returns null but I've never getting to the else clause in my conditional it always returns a stack trace with an error of:

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of null
```

I also tried the isNull method but would get the same results. Here's my code. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong this has to be something simple I'm missing. Thanks for the help!

```
InputStream input = conn.getInputStream()
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))
String line
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
   response.append(line)                
}

if(response.toString() != null || response.toString() != "null"){
    return new JSONObject(response.toString())
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: Could it be response.toString() != ""

Comment: Check if the response is empty. Try `if (response.toString().trim().length() != 0)`

Comment: Are you seriously Delmon Young, the baseball player who plays for the Orioles?

Comment: There's no way you're Delmon Young. He just played in the Orioles vs Astros game that ended two hours ago at 5PM ET.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 lol, I'm not Delmon Young but I do know him. I told him about my profile and he got a good kick out of it. Checking if the response is empty didn't work for me btw. Any other ideas?

Comment: `response.toString()` will never return `null`, because null is not a proper String representation of an object. It can return an empty string, though, which you can test using its length, or using `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)`

Comment: have you already checked the content of response before you actually try to convert it to JSON? You are reading directly from an input stream, chances are that you actually reading the whole HTTP response including `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and further headers instead of just the body - if so, skip the appending to the response buffer till you hit an empty line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(response != null && !response.toString().equals("null")){
    return new JSONObject(response.toString())
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Note the **&&** instead of **||** (which I'm sure is what you meant in the first place).

#### Edit

Just read your code a little more carefully: you don't need that first null check, you know the StringBuffer can't be null, and its .toString() will never return null, either. So, just: `if(!response.toString().equals("null")){}`

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dmitri let me give it a try. I swear I tried something similar with no luck. I'll let you know in a second.

Comment: Still getting the same error of A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of null any other ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the string actually is just 'null', with no whitespace (may have a newline?). Or test with .startsWith() or .matches()